# Remove: complete action using

Tags: android, android-manifest

I made two applications that use the bluetooth in the same way. When I click on the "Connect" button I get the message "complete action using..." with the choice of my two applications. How do I delete it and launch only the activity of the application that I am using?

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Bluetooth.connectedThread != null) {
        Bluetooth.connectedThread.write(" ");}//Stop streaming
    super.onBackPressed();
}


//toggle Button
static boolean Lock;//whether lock the x-axis to 0-5
static boolean AutoScrollX;//auto scroll to the last x value
static boolean Stream;//Start or stop streaming
boolean dark = true;
//Button init
Button bXminus;
Button bXplus;
Button bYminus;
Button bYplus;
ToggleButton tbScroll;
ToggleButton tbStream;
RadioButton ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4;
//GraphView init
static LinearLayout GraphView, GraphView1;

//graph value
private static double graph2LastXValue = 0;
private static int Xview=10;
Button bConnect, bDisconnect;
Button cambia;
Button bBackground;
int switches = 0;
int range = 1;
int counter = 0;

byte prova = (byte) 187; //188 e 168  

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case Bluetooth.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            Bluetooth.connectedThread = new Bluetooth.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            Bluetooth.connectedThread.start();
            Bluetooth.connectedThread.write(new byte[]{(byte) prova});
            break;
        case Bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ:

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int valore_a_16 = ((readBuf[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (readBuf[0] & 0xFF);
            int valore_a_16_2 = ((readBuf[3] & 0xFF) << 8) | (readBuf[2] & 0xFF);
            int valore_a_16_3 = ((readBuf[5] & 0xFF) << 8) | (readBuf[4] & 0xFF);
            int valore_a_16_4 = ((readBuf[7] & 0xFF) << 8) | (readBuf[6] & 0xFF);
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf);   // create string from bytes array
            String str = String.valueOf(valore_a_16);
            String str2 = String.valueOf(valore_a_16_2);
            String str3 = String.valueOf(valore_a_16_3);
            String str4 = String.valueOf(valore_a_16_4);
            Log.d("SHORT", str);
            Log.d("strIncom", strIncom);
            Log.d("SHORT CH 2", str2);
            Log.d("SHORT CH 3", str3);
            Log.d("SHORT CH 4", str4);
            char c = strIncom.charAt(0);
            long foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
            long foo2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
            long foo3 = Integer.parseInt(str3);
            long foo4 = Integer.parseInt(str4);
            //String provola = Integer.toString(foo);
            //Log.d("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA", provola);
         //   int decVal = (int) c;

            long risultato = (long) (foo * 5000000)/(65535*150);
            long risultato2 = (long) (foo2 * 5000000)/(65535*150);
            long risultato3 = (long) (foo3 * 5000000)/(65535*150);
            long risultato4 = (long) (foo4 * 5000000)/(65535*150);

            String prova = Float.toString(risultato);
            String prova2 = Float.toString(risultato2);
            String prova3 = Float.toString(risultato3);
            String prova4 = Float.toString(risultato4);
            Log.d("prova", prova);
    //        Log.d("testing2", String.valueOf(decVal));






            break;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFloatNumber(String num){
        //Log.d("checkfloatNum", num);
        try{
            Double.parseDouble(num);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Hide title
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.
            FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//Hide Status bar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //set background color
    LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bg);
    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    init();
    ButtonInit();
}

void init(){
    Bluetooth.gethandler(mHandler);




}


void ButtonInit(){
    bConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConnect);
    bConnect.setOnClickListener(this);
    bDisconnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bDisconnect);
    bDisconnect.setOnClickListener(this);
    //X-axis control button
    bXminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bXminus);
    bXminus.setOnClickListener(this);
    bXplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bXplus);
    bXplus.setOnClickListener(this);
    bYminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bYminus);
    bYminus.setOnClickListener(this);
    bYplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bYplus);
    bYplus.setOnClickListener(this);
    //
    tbScroll = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbScroll);
    tbScroll.setOnClickListener(this);
    tbStream = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbStream);
    tbStream.setOnClickListener(this);
    tbStream.setEnabled(false);
    bBackground = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bBackground.setOnClickListener(this);
//init toggleButton
    ch1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    ch1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ch1.setChecked(true);
    ch2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    ch2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ch3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    ch3.setOnClickListener(this);
    ch4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    ch4.setOnClickListener(this);
    Lock=false;
    AutoScrollX=true;
    Stream=true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bConnect:
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.BT1"));
        break;
    case R.id.bDisconnect:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RacerGameActivity.class);

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.bXminus:
        if (Xview>1) Xview=Xview/10;
        break;
    case R.id.bXplus:
        if (Xview<100) Xview=Xview*10;
        break;
    case R.id.bYminus:
        if (range==1)
        {

            range=0;
        }
        else if (range==0)
        {
            range=0;
        }
        else if(range==2)
        {

            range=1;
        }
        else if(range==3)
        {

            range=2;
        }
        else if(range==4)
        {

            range=3;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.bYplus:
        if (range==1)
        {

            range=2;
        }
        else if (range==0)
        {

            range=1;
        }
        else if(range==2)
        {

            range=3;
        }
        else if(range==3)
        {

            range=4;
        }
        else if(range==4)
        {

            range=4;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.tbScroll:
        if (tbScroll.isChecked()){
            AutoScrollX = true;
        }else{
            AutoScrollX = false;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton1:
        ch1.setChecked(true);
        ch2.setChecked(false);
        ch3.setChecked(false);
        ch4.setChecked(false);
        switches=0;
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        ch1.setChecked(false);
        ch2.setChecked(true);
        ch3.setChecked(false);
        ch4.setChecked(false);
        switches=1;
        break;  
    case R.id.radioButton3:
        ch1.setChecked(false);
        ch2.setChecked(false);
        ch3.setChecked(true);
        ch4.setChecked(false);
        switches=2;
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton4:
        ch1.setChecked(false);
        ch2.setChecked(false);
        ch3.setChecked(false);
        ch4.setChecked(true);
        switches=3;
        break;


/*  case R.id.tbStream:
        if (tbStream.isChecked()){
            if (Bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                Bluetooth.connectedThread.write("E");
        }else{
            if (Bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                Bluetooth.connectedThread.write("Q");
        }
        break;
//  case R.id.button1:
//      GraphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
//      break;


    case R.id.button1:




            switches=1;

        break;*/
    }
}



}
```

Comment: can you post you `startAvtivity()` code

Comment: You are asking to view something, without specifying what you want to view.
This will cause every activity that responds to `new Intent("android.intent.action.BT1")` to be shown in a chooser.

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: I changed the string from BT1 to BT2

Comment: ok, now is your problem solved ?